# Locales activation on buildroot based on gclibc

Tags: utf-8, locale, embedded-linux, glibc, buildroot

Could anyone help to activate locales on **gclibc-buildroot**? 
My system works fine, but there is problem. I don't see any russian letters (I need ru_RU of UTF-8 and CP1251).

I did:

```
System configuration -> Generate local data (en_US, ru_RU)
(*) Copy gconv libraries -> <empty> (all)
```

Some time before I successfully built buildroot on uclibc, where I used uclibc-menuconfig for settings of locales. But there is no gclibc-menuconfig for gclibc...

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared due to glibc upgrade to 2.27 version. There were changes in locale (alt names support). Buildroot's host version of localedef utility, which is used to compile locales, is uncompatible with locale definitions in new glibc.

You could downgrade glibc back to 2.26 for the workarond:

```
diff --git a/package/glibc/glibc.hash b/package/glibc/glibc.hash
index 1fab3a245c..150ba4a375 100644
--- a/package/glibc/glibc.hash
+++ b/package/glibc/glibc.hash
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 # Locally calculated (fetched from Github)
 sha256  33189b3f10c88730a1f686fac794bc01f31765f12ffd75bc5e8a0f2a690d217a     glibc-glibc-2.27-57-g6c99e37f6fb640a50a3113b2dbee5d5389843c1e.tar.gz
+sha256  0766875391224153502c5542a71b6e46db53b44691078b3130e1a0df41586430     glibc-glibc-2.26-107-g73a92363619e52c458146e903dfb9b1ba823aa40.tar.gz
 # Locally calculated (fetched from Github)
 sha256  ddc63360393ab88ab6a4a0c81d33481f34c5a9ebd758eec2e6bb35385058b4cb     glibc-arc-2018.03-rc2.tar.gz

diff --git a/package/glibc/glibc.mk b/package/glibc/glibc.mk
index f764b5da9c..ecab623a1a 100644
--- a/package/glibc/glibc.mk
+++ b/package/glibc/glibc.mk
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@ GLIBC_SITE = $(call github,foss-for-synopsys-dwc-arc-processors,glibc,$(GLIBC_VE
 else
 # Generate version string using:
 #   git describe --match 'glibc-*' --abbrev=40 origin/release/MAJOR.MINOR/master
-GLIBC_VERSION = glibc-2.27-57-g6c99e37f6fb640a50a3113b2dbee5d5389843c1e
+GLIBC_VERSION = glibc-2.26-107-g73a92363619e52c458146e903dfb9b1ba823aa40
 # Upstream doesn't officially provide an https download link.
 # There is one (https://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git) but it's not reliable,
 # sometimes the connection times out. So use an unofficial github mirror.
```